# Automation of clicks on webpage using Matlab

Tags: matlab, automation

So I'm looking for a way to systematically access data from a website. This data is updated every 15 minutes or so, and is generated through a datamart system that makes custom reports following several input parameters: the desired date interval, the specific dataset.

All these parameters require me to click on some specific buttons; I was wondering if it would be possible to automate these click inputs using Matlab (or something else if need be), to retrieve the data and treat it automatically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On linux, you can use: [`xdotool`](http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse) as a system tool.

Comment: Sadly I'm using Windows, and the autoclicking would have to occur as part of a script.

Comment: Do those buttons have some kind of keyboard shortcuts? That would make things easier. At any rate, you probably need to use Java (from Matlab). See for example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100545-how-can-i-programmatically-control-mouse-motion-and-clicks-with-matlab)

Comment: Yes the example suggested at this page will have to do. The challenge now is to make it so it is robust and doesn't click on the wrong buttons.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can have a look at Sikuli, it is made for this kind of problems and works great under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at http://www.autohotkey.com/.  This is a great tool which allows for the automatic clicking on any window (including a browser page) under Windows.  It even will let you "search" your screen for pixel images and then click on those images.  This would allow you to make a very small bmp file of the link you would like to click on, and then your script can search your page and click directly on the link.

As far as getting data into matlab I'm not exactly sure of the best way to do this, but you might consider saving the html of the page, and then parsing that from matlab.